# Swift : How to reset some NSUserDefaults everyday at 00:00

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

How to reset some NSUserDefaults everyday at 00:00
Ex.

```
if Time = 00:00/New day 
{
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("Data")
}
```

Comment: store current date and check if current time/day is +1 of the last stored day. you cant really do things at 00:00 since app cant launch themselves.

Comment: Looks like enough research has not been before asking this question. Simple googling would have given you many ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to wrap `NSUserDefaults` into a Dao: it will perform the logic you need retrieving the saved data or resetting the data.

### 1: Adding isToday to NSDate

First of all let's add a property to `NSDate`

```
extension NSDate {
    var isToday: Bool {
        let unitFlags : NSCalendarUnit = [.Year, .Month, .Day]
        let componentsSelf = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(unitFlags, fromDate: self)
        let componentsNow = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(unitFlags, fromDate: NSDate())
        return (componentsSelf.year,componentsSelf.month, componentsSelf.day) == (componentsNow.year,componentsNow.month, componentsNow.day)
    }
}
```

### 2: The Dao for NSUserDefaults

```
class UserDefaultsDao {
    static let sharedInstance = UserDefaultsDao()

    private var storage: NSUserDefaults { return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() }

    var data: String? {
        set {
            storage.setObject(newValue, forKey: "data")
            storage.setObject(NSDate(), forKey: "lastSet")
        }
        get {
            guard let lastSet = storage.objectForKey("dastSet") as? NSDate where lastSet.isToday else {
                storage.removeObjectForKey("data")
                return nil
            }
            return storage.objectForKey("data") as? String
        }
    }
}
```

### 3: Usage

This is how you save your data

```
UserDefaultsDao.sharedInstance.data = "hello world"
```

And this is how you print it

```
print(UserDefaultsDao.sharedInstance.data)
```

> Since NSUserDefaults does NOT work properly in Playground, you should test this on a real project.